# Bounded generic method not compiling - why?

Tags: java, generics

The code below makes complete sense to me - its about adding an element of some type which is supertype of type T and type S is definitely such a super type , so why the compiler refuses to add 'element' into the collection ?

```
class GenericType<S,T extends S>{
   void add1(Collection<? super T> col ,S element ){
        col.add(element);  // error
       // The method add(capture#9-of ? super T) in the type 
       // Collection<capture#9-of ? super T> is not applicable for the arguments (S)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection<? super T>` does *not* mean "a collection that can contain `T` and any superclass of it" - it's actually not possible to formulate that restriction. What it means is "a collection that can only contain instances of some specific class which is a superclass of `T`" - basically it ensures that you can add a `T` to the collection.

The method can be called with a `Collection<T>`, yet you want to add an `S` to it.

Comment: Given what you say , how is then this declaration different from something that does *not* use wildcard (  Collection<T> instead of Collection<? super T> ) ?

Comment: @Bhaskar: the wildcard also allows you to call the method with a Collection<S> or a Collection<Object> - everything you can add a T to.

Answer (score 5):

Thake an example, if `A <- B <- C` where `<-` means that is the supertype, then if `S = B` and `T = C` you cannot add an instance of `S` to a collection of `T`.

A supertype of `T` may be the supertype or a subtype of another supertype of `T` (in this case `S`).

Comment: yes I agree with your derivation , but the fact still remains that S is a supertype - so why is that fact not deemed sufficient for allowing this addition ? I can see that allowing so will also lead to a possible runtime exception , so is it because the designers decided to avoid getting into such runtime situations ? if you , then whats the difference between Collection<? super T> and Collection<T> in above usage ?

Comment: correct answer indeed , but have to give it to Michael for letting me understand it in prose.

Answer (score 2):

```
new GenericType<Object,Integer>().add1(new ArrayList<Integer>(), "");
```

Comment: +1 for a valid concrete and unsafe example.  Though it might be more clear that you're exercising the "super" keyword if you passed in an `ArrayList<Number>`.  Using `ArrayList<Integer>` does show the most obvious flaw in the OP's reasoning, in that `List<? super T>` admits a `List<T>` which obviously won't accept an arbitrary supertype of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put an element of type S into a collection of type T. Generics aren't polymorphic.
You have to take notice of 2 problems here. you are trying to create an Collection of type concreteObject extends Object and are adding an object
So when you have

```
Car extends Vehicle{}
ElectricCar extends Car{}
```

you are trying to do

```
Collection<? extends Car> collection;
collection.add(new Vehicle());
```

The second problem lies with the non-polymorphism nature of Generics. See this great explanation -> [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitl)